# Java: Selection sort of String array

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting

I am working on some sort algorithms for a school project and i have a problem .
The following code its not sorting the array,I have tried the same code with array of numbers(the only change is in the if) and it was working but now with the String array and the use of compareTo its not working its just puts the items in "random" order.

```
public static void selectionSortISBN(Book pin[], int booksCounter) {
    for (int x = 0; x < booksCounter; x++) {
        int minIndex = x;
        for (int y = x + 1; y < booksCounter; y++) {
            if (pin[y].getISBN().compareTo(pin[minIndex].getISBN()) < 0) {
                minIndex = y;
            }
        }
        Book temp = pin[x];
        pin[x] = pin[minIndex];
        pin[minIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I changed my inner for to this :

```
        for (int y = x + 1; y < booksCounter; y++) {
            int com=pin[y].getISBN().compareTo(pin[minIndex].getISBN());
            System.out.println(pin[y].getISBN()+"   "+pin[minIndex].getISBN()+"  =   "+com);
        }
```

and the output i am getting is this

```
1537   1485  =   1
596   1485  =   4
1164   1485  =   -3
909   1485  =   8
596   1537  =   4
1164   1537  =   -4
909   1537  =   8
1164   596  =   -4
909   596  =   4
909   1164  =   8
```

Comment: The code looks ok. Have you checked the input values? In particular, I would delete `booksCounter` and use `pin.length` instead

Comment: Are you sure the order is "Random"? Can you post an example of input and output?

Comment: You are sorting alphanumerically by ISBN, not by title, you are aware of that? Are they really "randomly" ordered by ISBN? What does "getISBN" do? maybe this function doesn't return the correct values.

Comment: @SJuan76  i dont use pin.lenght cuase the array is not always full.

Comment: @svinja yes i know ,i need to do the algorith for both the ISBN and the title both stored inside strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working correctly, the mistake you are making is that you expect "596" to be under "1485", when it is not, you are sorting them as strings, 596 > 1485 just like BA > AAAABA. Add leading zeroes if you want to compare numbers alphanumerically.

Comment: It may be better to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing only with numbers then convert your array of string to array of numbers